# Is there a patten match with Writer Monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

What is correct way to do pattern match with Writer Monad in Haskell?

I want to do like following...

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
hoge :: Writer [Int] (Int, String) -> String
hoge (Writer (_, (_, s))) = s
```

Actually, I don't really know difference between `Writer` and `WriterT` and `Writer.Identity`, etc...

Any guidance would be appreciated, Thank you for your reading.

Comment: You might want to view the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html#Writer) of Writer and WriterT

Comment: Why do you want to make a writer when you discard the written results afterwards? Or to phrase it differently why do you need a writer and can't you just use a pure function?

Comment: Above function is just sample. In real code, I always use Writer with monad functions (>>=).

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly what you're trying to do, you can use `runWriter` to get `((Int, String), [Int])` out of your `Writer`, and then extract the string from that. Something like `snd . fst . runWriter ...`, perhaps.

`WriterT` is what you use when you need to combine a `Writer` with some other monad. Rather than writing separate-but-similar implementations for `Writer` and `WriterT`, it was easier to write just the implementation for `WriterT`, and define `Writer` as a `WriterT` that uses the `Identity` monad. The `Identity` monad doesn't really do anything; you can simply pretend it's not there.

Comment: Thanks. I know `runWriter` function. But `let s = snd $ fst $ runWriter w` is too long. I wish I could get the content with pattern match.

Comment: You cann't pattern match on it as it is not a new data type